# how to retrive data from database and bind into html form by using ajax in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

how to retrieve data from SQL server into html form textboxes by using ajax call in asp.net core ?
(or)
retrieve data from SQL server into html form textboxes in asp.net core?

Comment: PHP and ASP.NET Core both are different technologies so please describe your question properly what you wanted to do?

Comment: Do you have any code to prove you attempted to beat the challenge and then encountered a problem?

Comment: i think now it clear

Comment: Dong li yes i tried to implement the logic in this way that i created list for storing data from the database in the model and i tried to access that model through controller then i tried to call that controller through ajax. while executing that ajax is calling the controller controller is accepting model logic but data is not populating into form textboxes.

Comment: Could you please share the related codes, if you have it?

Comment: I'm assuming this is an auto-fill kind of thing?  You can use an Ajax call to a .cs file which returns JSON.  Then populate the inputs accordingly.  In the callback you'd have something like this if you use jQuery and callback assigns 'data' as return value:  if (data != "" && data != null) {
            if (data.name != "") { $("#" + "YourInput_Name").val(data.name); }

Comment: The controller method would be declared as public JsonResult OnPostAsync()... and return as:  return new JsonResult(item);  where item is a controller class model.

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-in-net-core/)